# Can't Initialize Router

Tags: routes, sapui5

I am having issues trying to initialize the router of SAPUI5.
This is my webapp folder structure:
[webapp folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xTBY.jpg)

At the bottom of the manifest, I defined all routing config, routes and targets:

```
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "viewPath": "ar.com.ordago.FSOT.view",
        "controlId": "app",
        "controlAggregation": "pages",
        "transition": "slide",
        "async": true
    },
    "routes": [{
         "pattern": "",
         "name": "appHome",
         "target": "home"
    }],
    "targets": {
         "home": {
                "viewId": "home",
                "viewName": "Home",
                "viewLevel" : 1
        }
    }
```

My App.view:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="ar.com.ordago.FSOT.controller.App"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
xmlns="sap.m">
  <App id="app"/>
</mvc:View>
```

My Home.view

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="ar.com.ordago.FSOT.controller.Home"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns="sap.m">
    <pages>
        <Page
            id="page"
            title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
            </content>
         </Page>
    </Pages>
</mvc:View>
```

Then at the Component.js I try to create the instance of the router (I include all the beginning of it just in case):

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
"sap/m/MessageToast",
"sap/ui/Device",
"sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
"./model/models",
"./model/formatter"
], function(UIComponent, MessageToast, Device, JSONModel, models) {
"use strict";

return UIComponent.extend("ar.com.ordago.FSOT.Component", {

    metadata: {
        manifest: "json"
    },

    /**
     * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
     * @public
     * @override
     */

    init : function() {
        // call the base component's init function
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
        // set the device model
        this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
        // create the views based on the url/hash
        this.getRouter().initialize();


    }
```

And when I run the webapp, I get the following error: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined

I searched here, many people have similar issues.  But for every solution suggested, problem was that there were not having the UIcomponent.prototype... call at init function in component.js, but I do have it, so I do not know what to do next to solve this.

I appreciate your help here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Problem was that the indentation used in manifest.js was corrupted.  All the information related to routes and navigation was at the same level of node "sap.ui5", when they need to be at a lower level of that node.
In essence, since I am mixing many technologies, I was not coding through SAP WebIDE.  But in order to solve this, I loaded the project in the WebIDE and I was able to see the error.
I guess that when dealing with SAPUI5 controls it is better to maintain it through the WebIDE.